# java open pdf file on client side in adobe reader

Tags: java, file, pdf, client, adobe

In Java Web Application, I have to open PDF file in client machine which is available in share that too without copying to client side. It should open in adobe reader in client side.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is located on the client side, If he double clicks the file, it would open in the Adobe reader  :-)

But the server can't open a file located on the client side. If the web application needs to open then the file needs to be present in the server readable location. You can write a servlet to open the PDF file.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = null;
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
try {

    // Public user guide
    String fileName = "MyFile.pdf";


    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
    bufferedInputStream.read(data);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(servletOutputStream);
    bufferedOutputStream.write(data);

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e);
} finally {

    if (bufferedInputStream != null) {
        bufferedInputStream.close();
    }

    if (bufferedOutputStream != null) {
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
    }

    if (servletOutputStream != null) {
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```